# Microsoft announced support for OpenID a few years ago. Where do I find it?

Tags: windows-live, openid

A few years ago Microsoft said that [Windows Live ID would be an OpenID provider](http://techcrunch.com/2008/10/27/windows-live-adds-support-for-openid-calls-it-de-facto-login-standard/). Have they actually gotten around to implementing it, and if so, where is the service URL?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056263/is-windows-live-id-an-openid-provider

Comment: @Mike Scott How can it be a duplicate of a question from another site targeting different type of users?

Comment: @mike-scott How am I supposed to find it there if I was just looking here? I'm not looking to write anything with their API, I was just looking to use it, which is why I came to Super User.

Comment: @CyberSkull It's the seventh result on Google for '"windows live" openid'. It's hardly unreasonable to expect people to look through the first page of search results on Google before asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

There <s>is</s> isn't OpenID support for Windows Live.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID

**edit**

Ack, I meant to write it isn't implemented.  Funny how one omission changes everything.

Comment: Can you please provide a quote form that page that actually shows that microsoft provided an OpenID provider for Live platform?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why all the downvotes.  Then I read what I typed. . .

Comment: All the Wikipedia article really says is they announced it, and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to type that it **isn't** supported.